# Microsoft Access 2007 SQL Design Query Assistance Requested

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am receiving this error in MS Access:

> The SELECT Statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

The compiler is highlighting the O in O/H from the second line below, but I don't think that is the cause of the error.  If you see any additional errors, please let me know and provide the corrected code.  I am appreciative of all help.

```
SELECT Inventory.Item_No, Inventory.NDC, Pharmacy.NDC_Desc,        
ROUND(Inventory.OH_Qty_EA/Pharmacy.McK_PackQty,0) AS ‘McKesson O/H Qty’, SUM((Purchases.SUOM_Orders/COUNT(Purchases.SUOM_Orders)) * Pharmacy.Safecor_PackQty*1.5/Pharmacy.McK_PackQty) AS 'Avg Par (in McKesson SUOM)', 
SUM((Purchases.SUOM_Orders/COUNT(Purchases.SUOM_Orders)) * Pharmacy.Safecor_PackQty*1.5/Pharmacy.McK_PackQty) – SUM(Inventory.OH_Qty_EA) AS 'Avg Qty to Order (in McKesson SUOM)'
FROM (Inventory
    LEFT JOIN Pharmacy ON Inventory.Item_No=Pharmacy.Item_No)
    LEFT JOIN Purchases ON Pharmacy.Item_No=Purchases.Item_No
WHERE Purchases.Order_Date>=DATE()-120
ORDER BY Inventory.Item_No ASC;
```

thorntonehc:  I am getting the error Cannot have aggregate function in expression.  It's not liking the SUM divided by Count.

Comment: Ignore the "your text" parts.  I was trying to post the script and tried to conform to the forum's syntax as best as I could

Comment: Haven't used Access in ages, but if you want spaces in an aliased column name, wouldn't you use square brackets? Or, perhaps you have the wrong single quotes for _McKesson O/H Qty_.

Comment: Yes, square brackets it is.

Comment: I am still getting an error:  "Cannot have aggregate function in expression SUM(Purchases.SUOM.Orders/COUNT(Purchases.SUOM_Orders)*Pharmacy.Safecor_PackQty*1.5/Pharmacy.McK_PackQty))

Comment: You need the GROUP BY clause in your query otherwise the SQL engine has no idea what you want to aggregate.

Comment: GROUP BY is not needed if you want to aggregate all records to a single output. However, your error message is explicit. Possibly you need a subquery. Edit question to provide sample data and desired output as formatted text tables.

Comment: You can do something like: `SELECT Table1.*, (SELECT Sum(Qty) / Count(*) FROM Table2) * 1.5 AS X FROM Table1`. Modify as appropriate for your requirement.